# Error Editor or Editor Extension System.TypeInitializationException

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I've been using SQL Server 2014 for months. Opened the studio and tried to query for the contents of a small table and I get this error...

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Babel.LineScanner' threw an exception. ---> System.BadImageFormatException: File is corrupt.

Does this mean that there's a SQL library that's corrupted or that my SQL Server database files are corrupted? This error happens no matter which database I query. Any clues on what to do next?

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall all of the .NET components and reinstall with updates? Check here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195919/ssms-2014-gives-an-exception-when-opening-the-new-query-window

Comment: @jacDeveloper : rather than given answer, add a comment here, Original text in answer "A reboot solved the problem. Weird."